# Maximal ideals of polynomial rings in infinitely many variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Nullstellensatz states that the maximal ideals of the polynomial ring $R=k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ are precisely those of the form $\langle X_1-a_1,\dots,X_n-a_n\rangle$, with $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in k^n$.

> What if we are working with infinitely many variables, say $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$, being $I$ an infinite set? Again, the ideals of the form $\bigl\langle\{X_i-a_i: i\in I\}\bigr\rangle$, with $(a_i)_{i\in I}\subseteq k$ are maximal (even if $k$ is not algebraically closed), but what about the converse?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let $k$ be a field and let $K$ be an extension of $k$ of degree larger than $1$. Let $R=k[X_i, i\in K]$ be a polynomial ring with one variable per element of $K$. There is a $k$-linear ring homomorphism $\phi:R\to K$ which maps $X_i$ to $i$ for all $i\in K$, and it is surjective. It follows that the kernel of $\phi$ is maximal. Clearly, it is not of the form you mentioned: indeed, the quotient of $R$ by all ideals of that form is $1$-dimensional as a $k$-algebra.

Comment: Notice that even if $k$ is algebraically closed this gives examples: it is enough to take $K=k(x)$, a field of rational functions, for example.

Comment: Very ingenious, Mariano: bravo!

Answer (score 7):

If $|k| > |I|$, then any maximal ideal of $k[\{x_i\}_{i \in I}]$ is of the standard form, see [MO/41262](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41262/maximal-ideals-of-kx-1-x-2). The "cheap proof" of the Nullstellensatz works. The example by Mariano shows that this doesn't hold if $|k|=|I|$.