# Are there maximal ideals of $k[x_1, x_2, \ldots]$ (infinite indeterminates) that are not $(x_1 - a_1, \ldots...)$ for $k$ algebraically closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Are there maximal ideals of $k[x_1, x_2, \ldots]$ (infinite indeterminates) that are not $(x_1 - a_1, \ldots...)$ for $k$ algebraically closed?

I don't think one can apply the Nullstellensatz here...

just thinking about weird counter examples in algebraic geometry, and I'm curious since this ring $k[x_1, \ldots]$ has come up a few times.

Note that there are a countable set of indeterminates.

Comment: You can see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543350/maximal-ideals-of-polynomial-rings-in-infinitely-many-variables), and also, for another form of Nullstellensatz this [short paper](http://www.google.fr/url?url=http://www.ams.org/proc/1952-003-03/S0002-9939-1952-0047019-0/S0002-9939-1952-0047019-0.pdf&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&sa=U&ved=0CBQQFjAAahUKEwjW0sHd4PLHAhXGMhoKHfQMDgQ&sig2=fL8LAqS8VUOIpq64qUaU2g&usg=AFQjCNGm1cSVggdr0nCle4lUEsuDqY_bUA) by Serge Lang.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks. That argument of Mariano's is extremely clever! I'll have to remember that trick...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if and only if $k$ is countable.

Every maximal ideal of the form $(x_1-a_1,\ldots)$ is the kernel of a $k$-algebra homomorphism $k[x_1,\ldots] \to k$.  To construct a maximal ideal not of this form, it is sufficient to construct a surjection of $k$-algebras $k[x_1,\ldots] \to l$, where $l\neq k$ is a field extension of $k$.

For example, let $l=k(t)$ be the field of rational functions over $k$, and send the $x_i$ to a set of $k$-algebra generators for $l$.

If $k$ is uncountable, then it has no nontrivial countably-generated extensions, and so every maximal ideal is of the form $(x_1-a_1,\ldots)$.

Comment: For the last observation, this is essentially that one needs uncountably many generators to account even for fractions like $\frac{1}{rx_0 + x_1}$, for $r \in k$ when $x_0$ and $x_1$ are algebraically independent over $k$. Right? Or is it more subtle?

Comment: @AreaMan That's essentially it.  The way I would put it is that there are uncountably many monic irreducibles in $k[t]$, even if we just restrict to degree 1.

Answer (score 0):

This question is essentially answered here, as Bernard's comment points out:

[Maximal ideals of polynomial rings in infinitely many variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543350/maximal-ideals-of-polynomial-rings-in-infinitely-many-variables)

It is false that all ideals are of that form; one can construct a surjective map to a proper extension of $k$ by labeling the indeterminates by elements of the field $k(x)$, then mapping each indeterminate to its indexing element. (It is necessary that there be a cardinality $|k|$ generating set for $k(x)$.)