# What is a maximal ideal of the ring of polynomials of infinitely many variables?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I've just started to learn Noetherian rings and struggling to understand.
So, I learned

> A commutative ring R is Noetherian iff it satisfies the ascending chain condition on ideals iff it satisfies the maximum condition on ideals (maximum condition: every non-empty set of ideals of R contains a maximal element)

Also, I googled the non-example of Notherian rings and found that the ring of polynomials

> Consider the ring of polynomials $\mathbb R[x_1,x_2,...]$ of inifintely many variables. Consider $$(x_1)\subset (x_1,x_2)\subset ...\subset (x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\subset...$$ 
>   This infinite chain of ideals does not stablize. Hence $\mathbb R[x_1,x_2,...]$ is not Noetherian. (http://mathonline.wikidot.com/noetherian-rings)

So $\mathbb R[x_1,x_2,...]$ must not satify the maximum condtion on ideals. I think      $$J=\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_k):k\in\mathbb N \} $$does not satisfy the maximum condition. However, I also learned that every ideal in a commutative ring with unity always have a maximal ideal and every ideal in R is contained in a maximal ideal. But then what is the maximal ideal of $\mathbb R[x_1,x_2,...]$?

Comment: the maximal ideal is the one generated by the $x_i.$

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543350/maximal-ideals-of-polynomial-rings-in-infinitely-many-variables

Comment: There is no "the maximal ideal" of the ring, there are many...

Comment: @augustoC  Thank you so much!